# Can i use firebase + spring boot at same time in Ionic app

Tags: spring, database, firebase, ionic-framework, mobile

I'm building a mobile app in ionic and i want to know if i can use firebase and spring boot at the same time in the same app so i can benefit firebase real-time database and authentication and use my custom APIs in spring. If anyone has used it before, tell how it was and can they work efficiently at the same time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say yes.
We used firebase for Push Notifications and our BE was Spring Boot.

What will you use your custom APIs for? CRUD? if so, this might help: https://medium.com/techwasti/spring-boot-firebase-crud-b0afab27b26e